# How to get picture in private message as the same size as facebook site?

Tags: facebook, message, image

I could get link of pictures in private message.
And at most time, I could get smaller one by replay the part "/v/" in link by "/s320x320/".
But not for every picture.

Here is my question.
How could I get the same size picture as the Facebook site?
*in Feed case, they response many links, but not in private message case.

Hope for your help.
And I couldn't get any answer from Facebook in Japan and don't hope to get one. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand this question

Comment: Does this help?http://graph.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage/picture?type=large

Comment: Could you don't tell me you don't understand? or tell me where you don't understand? In one word, there are many picture in many size, and I want to get the smaller one in private message.

Comment: @sinisterfrog thank you. I will check that one. Is that the icon in profile?

Comment: Yes, it's the profile picture for 'stackoverflowpage' - replace this with the username or Facebook ID of whatever you need.